# How do i recover oracle sys password for oracle 12c when login as sqlplus / as sysdba

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have got a DB Oracle 12c R2 and i am able to login as:

$sqlplus / as sysdba

But however my problem is that i dont even know what is the sys password used there just in case I need to do db recovery. How do i get the existing password without changing the current sys password.

Answer (score 0):

Not.
What you can do is to change the password.
Since the password hashing is more or less protected it should be possible to decode it somehow but that will take time.

Normally we don't use that password at all.

Normally we don't /hardly use the sys account.

Answer (score 0):

The connections "/ as sysdba" is using OS authentication.  That is, the fact that the logged on user (logged on at the OS) is a member of the OS group "dba", tell oracle that the user is "good to go".   If the logged on OS user is *not* a member of the group "dba", then he would have to supply a username and password.  And logging on as sysdba, would have to be listed in the password file.

It is not possible to recover/learn the existing password.  It is stored as a one-way, non-reversable hash.

Comment: So if the database crashes and i want recover the database in RMAN using the SYS user, will it not ask me for SYS Password to start the recovery as SYS?

Comment: What happens when you try it for yourself?  You don't have to actually attempt a restore - just connect rman to the target database.

Comment: RMAN> connect target

connected to target database: TOPROD (DBID=2199595426)

RMAN>

Comment: So it appears you have your answer.